# Newton's 3rd law and rocket nozzles

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, rocket-science

For a given solid propellent charge the energy given off by the charge is equivalent in all cases. Yet by varying the throat of the nozzle, the rocket velocity will be different for each individual throat. Total energy given off and total mass remains identical. How does this not conflict with the 3rd law?

Comment: You might find that the NASA article [Nozzle Design](https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/rocket/nozzle.html) answers your question?

Comment: Just because thrust comes out of every nozzle does not mean that the thrust pushing the rocket forward is the same in all configurations.

Comment: I'm even thinking in even simpler terms if you pump up a water rocket. Say 5 ounces of water and 10 pumps of air depending on the diameter of the outlet you get different results yet all the net forces are the same. Who's wrong me or Newton? Grin ps did I ever tell you folks that black holes are nature's garbage disposals, turning mater into new space surrounding them thus explaining the expansion of the universe.

Answer (score 0):

the anser is clear. when the exit area of nozzle decreas, the surface of interaction nozzle will be change upward of to the nozzle and so on the reaction force for this type of nozzle will be upwward the rocket motion instead of side of it.
when the area of exit nozzle increase, the side area of nozzle to create reaction force will be increase and vice versa.